# sql reporting serices not showing anything when go to web interface

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

A client has installed Sql server 2005 reporting services. When we go to the web bit at `http://servername/reports/` we just see a blank screen like: 
[image: http://img91.imageshack.us/img91/3787/rsblankqx4.jpg]

We are using windows authentication and I think it has authenticated us as the "site settings" button is appearing and we can alter site security, add to roles etc.

I have had this before and cant remember how I fixed it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client reinstalled and this then worked fine. Must have become corrupted in some way.

Comment: What did you reinstall? SQL Server Reporting Services?
I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have access to any reports? Login as an admin user and make sure to give him access to the reports

Comment: Its a new installation so there are no existing reports but there is not the option to create anything either. It is missing the tool bar with the new folder, new data source options

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the reports website and reports server are running on the correct version of ASP.Net?